# Histogram with multiple x axis

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I will try to explain this the best I can without having found an example of exactly what I'm trying to produce. I need to create a single density histogram which has 3 different variables on it, and therefore shows three grouped x axis (as in fig 1) but each variable needs a separate x axis as the range of values are so different (see example data). I would also like to colour match each x axis to its variable for clarity (as in fig 2)

```
set.seed(1981)
x<-rnorm(400000, 0,1)
y<- rnorm(400000, 150, 770)
z<-rnorm(400000, 2000,10500)
mydata<-data.frame(x, y, z)
```

I created fig 1 using multhist:

```
multhist(mydata, col=mycol, freq=FALSE, ylab="Density")
```

[image]

[image]

I would really appreciate any help on this and am also open to an alternative way of plotting it if more appropriate. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you can achive such result in R [without hard coding]. Can't you re-center your data on the respective means?

Comment: Multiple axis plots are very confusing, use facets instead